# Javafx How to select filtered value from Tableview on button click

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml, javafx-11

i am new to Java FX and trying to implement a table view with filter using a textfield. i have a textfield and search button along with it. my requirement is i will enter a search value in textfield and click the search button. if the value is in the table i need to load another fxml(passing the selected value as an argument to that fxml and controller).But i am unable to get the filtered value to handleSearch() method.

FXML File(TableView textField and Button)

```
   <TableView fx:id="mTableView" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="451.0" prefWidth="929.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="idColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="salColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Salary" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
....
....

    <TextField fx:id="mTextField" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="366.0" />
                                <Button fx:id="searchBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleSearch" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="166.0"  text="Search" />
```

..

```
Controller 

 @FXML
    private TableView<Employee> mTableView;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, Integer> idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, String> nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, String> salColumn;

 ObservableList<Employee>  mList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@FXML
    public void handleSearch(ActionEvent event) {
 // need to get selected value here to load another fxml
}


 public void loadRecords(){
//this method is called to populate the tableview with data from DB( called from initialize() method of the controller)
...
...
 idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
            nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));
            salColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salary"));
            mTableView.setItems(mList);
            FilteredList<Employee> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(mList,b->true);
            mTextField.textProperty().addListener(((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                key = null;
                filteredList.setPredicate(cinema -> {
                    if(newValue.isEmpty() || newValue.isBlank() || newValue == null){
                        return true;
                    }
                    String searchKeyword = newValue.toLowerCase();
                  
                    if(isContain(cinema.getId().toString().toLowerCase(),searchKeyword)){
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }));
            SortedList<Employee> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);
            key = filteredList.get(0).getId().toString();
            sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(mTableView.comparatorProperty());
            mTableView.setItems(sortedList);
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `mTableView.getItems()` to get the sorted, filtered list. Then you can check if it’s empty, get elements from it, etc.

Comment: You could also simply make the `sortedList` an instance variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the list from the table when you need it:

```
@FXML
public void handleSearch(ActionEvent event) {
    List<Employee> employees = mTableView.getItems();
    if (! employees.isEmpty()) {
        // get first item:
        Employee firstSearchResults = employees.get(0);
        // now do whatever you need
        // You may want special handling if there is more than one result, etc.
    }
}
```